# Binding multiple DropDownLists to the same datasource

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My mark-up page is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Value" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Value" />
```

My code is:

```
class grade
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<grade> gradeList = new List<grade>()
      { new grade {Description="Poor", Value="1"}, 
          new grade { Description="Average", Value="2"}, 
          new grade {Description="Good", Value="4" } };
    //in real life the above list is read from a database

    DropDownList1.DataSource = gradeList;   DropDownList1.DataBind();
    DropDownList2.DataSource = gradeList;   DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

The above works fine for me.  I am able to change SelectedValue as well as SelectedIndex at run time for both DropDownLists without errors.  May I know whether the above is kosher.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any problem? I think it's ok

Comment: Well, explain more the issue! I don't see anything!

Comment: The above works fine, even though two DDLs are sharing one gradeList object.  My problem crops up when I started to do more and I will post that in a follow on question.  I just wanted to isolate the issues and first establish that the above method of sharing lists is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its perfectly fine to use like this. But you could use `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of Grade class.

Comment: Yes, I think the DataBind method creates a new instance of the list items and there is no pointing to a common list.  Anyway they are of different types. So it won't give the "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList." error.

Comment: No, I think your understanding is wrong. They both point to same object and data bind method won't create new instances. You will receive that error if there are multiple items selected in your dropdown,i.e, selectedindex or any other property like selecteditem that is allowing two selections for one dropdown list. So, it is independent of your object assignment and data bind methods.

Comment: ?? Then why did you say its perfectly fine?  They can't be pointing to the same object.  DropDownList.Items is ItemCollection.  Whereas my datasource is a List<grade>.  The DataBind process should be creating a new ItemCollection and filling it with ListItem updated with values from List<grade>.

Comment: I said its perfectly fine to bind dropdowns to same list. Internally I don't know how it manages, it may create two objects as you mentioned but I guess it just generates the html output pointing to same object. You can check it using reflector though. But my point is the error you mentioned is not because of this.